# Closeness of Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, approximation, approximation-theory

Given $S = \{e^{i\theta}: \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$,  $f: S \to\mathbb{C}$, and $g: S \to\mathbb{C}$ I'm trying to choose a definition to represent how well $f$ approximates $g$ on the unit circle. There are 2 definitions I've thought of:

1. $\int_0^{2\pi}\vert\vert f(e^{i\theta}) - g(e^{i\theta})\vert\vert \>d\theta$
2. An inner product definition like:
   $$\vert\vert f - g\vert\vert^2 = \><f-g,f-g> \>= \int_0^{2\pi}(f(e^{i\theta}) - g(e^{i\theta})) \overline{(f(e^{i\theta}) - g(e^{i\theta}))} \>d\theta$$

I'm not sure which to choose, and I'm not quite sure how to approach the "which is better?" question. Any insight into what each of these entities would represent intuitively, or which is a better measure of the quality of an approximation is appreciated! If it makes things easier, for my specific use case both $f$ and $g$ are polynomials.

Comment: Your first definition is the norm on $L^1(S)$ and your second is the norm on $L^2(S)$. Both are Banach spaces, but $L^2(S)$ has the additional structure of being a Hilbert space (you have an inner product). Which is better depends on what properties you want your approximation to have. Are there any properties you would like to have with your approximation?

Comment: @Zorngo To be honest, I'm not sure. Here's what I'm trying to do: I've come up with an algorithm to build polynomials of unitaries within a quantum circuit. The polynomial built depends on a set of parameters, and I would like to be able to make claims about what family of polynomials are possible to build with my algorithm. I haven't been able to do it mathematically, so now I want to try and go about it numerically by picking a polynomial and then optimizing over the variables to approximate it; so now  I'm trying to pick an objective function to optimize over.

Comment: It may not be useful in your case, but in many instances when approximating functions by polynomials people use the supremum norm $\|f - g\|_{\infty} := \sup_{\theta} |f(e^{i\theta}) - g(e^{i\theta})|$ because it gives you access to the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. For well behaved functions you could probably approximate the supremum norm numerically by uniformly sampling $\theta$.